# Converting text to PDF in Android, using iText

Tags: android, pdf

I tried to convert a text to PDF in Android, using iText ([here](http://www.geek-tutorials.com/java/itext/setup_itext.php)  ), but it gives the "File not found" exception. 
Here is the code:

```
try
        {

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("hello.pdf"));
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.close();
            Log.d("OK", "done");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (DocumentException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Would you please help me? Thanks

Comment: where is your file(file location)? is in project folder or on system drive?

Comment: Actually I used exactly the above code. So, I think the OS should create a new file in program folder.

Comment: I recomend you to use https://code.google.com/p/droidtext/. This is better for Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works perfect in my case,

```
try
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello.pdf"));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        document.close();
        Log.d("OK", "done");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (DocumentException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And in manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Location of hello.pdf is "/mnt/sdcard/hello.pdf".

Comment: Thanks, but what about the case when there is no SD card ?

Comment: Before creating a file just check for Environment.getExternalStorageState() it will returns path to internal SD mount point like "/mnt/sdcard"

Comment: And to write a file in application package directory use FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me... Try this

try
        {

```
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/hello/";
        File file = new File(path+"hello.pdf"); 
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            try { 
                file.createNewFile(); 

            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } 
            }
        }

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                 +File.separator
                 +"hello" //folder name
                 +File.separator
                 +"hello.pdf"));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World "+txt.getText() ));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World" +txt.getText()));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World" +txt.getText()));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World "+txt.getText()));
        document.close();
        Log.d("OK", "done");
```